# Chat application android guidance

Tags: android, mysql

I'm trying to create a chat application and I need a little bit of guidance. I have a login system in place which is working. The user logs in/registers and everything is stored in a mysql database on the server.I know how to handle post requests and send stuff back.I have a recyclerView that can display the messages, but my problem is as follows:

Let's say I have 2 android devices: Android1 and Android2. Android1 sends a message to Android2. The message gets stored to the server. How do I tell the server to direct that message to Android2, and how do I make Android2 receive the message.

What if Android2 was offline at that time.Do I create some sort of response from the phone to tell the server that the message wasn t delivered so it can be sent again? And now how do I program the server to send the message again?

The messages table should be something like- senderId, receiverId, message; or what's the best way of designing it?

I found out about that I can do it either by using GCM, PHP and MYSQL from here http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-1/ and also that I can use XMPP. Which approach is best? I prefer the first one because I understand it and it's easy to implement. I have no idea what's happening with XMPP. I created a windows server using firebase, but can I still use my php one somehow ? And also the connection confuses me. I have facebook login implemented. Are there any good tutorials on the xmpp+android out there. I found some, but they are unclear.

Edit: Why is this question getting down votes? What's so wrong with it?

Comment: As you already have a database, you can make you application, query the database at certain interval (each 10 seconds for example). Query the database, based on the user id of the user who has logged in your application. Your recycler view should refresh after each request and if there will be new messages, it will be updated. As a second option ,you can also set a flag in your table which gets updated when new messages are added in the table and the application will see, if the flag is set or not. If yes, it will fetch the new messages.

Comment: @PrerakSola aren't there too many requests ? Is that the best way to design it ? What about the messages table? Is my way of doing it appropriate ?

Comment: What about using tcp/ws  connection ?

Comment: @Krish I have no idea what that is. Thanks for suggesting. I'll have a look.

Comment: What about using sockets? There are so many ways to achieve this

Comment: I know that there are plenty. I found at least 3, but XMPP sounds like the best choice. Unfortunately I can't find how to create my own database and realise the android connection. I want to have the same freedom as I have with php+mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to face exactly the same situation as this sometime ago. What I have found in my researches was:

1. **[Use Telegram API](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram)**: telegram is a well consolidate open source app for chat messages, it handles all aspects of it, including security and all the UI stuff. Its license, although, oblies you to make your code open as well;
2. **Use [Google Cloud Message](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) Service**: GCM allows you to send push to many devices using either REST or XMPP. Even if you're using GCM you'll have to implement a lot by yourself. In my humble opinion this is the best solution;
3. **Implement a socket to connect the clients with the app server**: this will required a whole lot of work, from sync to managing the power that your app consume, I wouldn't recommend you to follow this;

### Understand the basics...

- **[Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol (XMPP):](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol)**

  > Is a communications protocol for message-oriented middleware based on
  >   XML (Extensible Markup Language).[1](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram) It enables the near-real-time
  >   exchange of structured yet extensible data between any two or more
  >   network entities
- **[REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)**:

  > Is an architectural style consisting of a coordinated set of
  >   architectural constraints applied to components, connectors, and data
  >   elements, within a distributed hypermedia system. REST ignores the
  >   details of component implementation and protocol syntax in order to
  >   focus on the roles of components, the constraints upon their
  >   interaction with other components, and their interpretation of
  >   significant data elements.[4](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram) Through the application of REST
  >   architectural constraints certain architectural properties are
  >   induced: Performance, Scalability, Simplicity, Modifiability,
  >   Visibility, Portability, and Reliability.[4](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram)

From above we can understand that REST and XMPP are nothing more than protocols that you might end up using in order to pass your data through the components of your architecture. XMPP is the most optimized protocol for instant message communication, however, it is a bit more complex to implement. Fortunatelly, GCM support both protocols.

### A possible architecture...

An instant message app is like any other client-server App. What is crucial to them is the need to notify the clients of updates that happen in the server. To do so, you need a proper way to communicate two clients. Usually this is made through a common app server. If you decide to go with GCM approach (my suggestion), you would have the following components:

- **GCM App Server**: Responsible to manage the token generation and forward the received message to their targets;
- **Custom App Server**: back end of the system implemented by you;
- **Client**: web, android or iOS device that will receive push notifications;

It all starts when client opens the app, it will then make a call directly to GCM to request a token. Once it possess a token, the device should synchronize it with Custom App Server - so it knows everybody connected to the system and how to get to them. Custom app server maintain the token information in DB. When a device wants to send a message to another one, it will send a request to the custom app server which will, by its turn, retrieve the token of the target and forward the request to GCM App Server. It will then make a push to the target.

### A Real Example...

As I said, I had to do a simmilar solution as I described above. The result of my work can be found in the following repositories:

1. [Instachat Android](https://github.com/instachat/android): contains the source code for an App that uses GCM - it looks a lot like Whats App;
2. [Instachat Core](https://github.com/instachat/core): a back end implemented using Spring Boot;

Both apps above were tested for a single one-to-one conversation using GCM and REST protocols, however, I'm still working on that and many bugs are present but the code can be used as a reference in order to understand the proposed architecture.

Hope I could help.

Comment: Thank you. Your response is on point. I also want to go for GCM, but a lot of people told me that it's not the right fit for instant messaging. Do you think that this is a good tutorial for that http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-1/ ? I know that it's working. I tested some of it. Do you think that I can use the same system to send files and other things too or does this tutorial that I've shared only work with messages?

Comment: Actually GCM is build for this type of service! I also thought at first that it wouldn't be able to perform good at this type of service - or that it would have some type of limitation - but no, it is the perfect approach for this situation! Regarding the tutorial, I would stick with the official website (I've provided the link in the answer). It tells all you need to know to use GCM. Check out instachat library as a reference if have some doubt

Comment: Tried to go through your files, but that is not a working application, right? I mean I can't find any activity/fragment file.

Comment: It is a working app, perhaps you have checked the core project that represents the back end, check the Android project

Comment: I checked the right one. I can't find the fragment files unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GCM for sending and receiving messages.
You just need to send your messages to the receiving device through GCM, it will take care of it even if the receiving device is offline.

Comment: I know that's possible(I found a tutorial), but I would rather implement something myself, if I knew where and how to start.

Answer (score 0):

> I used socket service  for chat. so, I recommend you to use socket for
>   that. As compare to other, it will get quick response and all that you
>   want.

Comment: Thank you. I was considering that, but I didn t know if it was the right fit. Everybody is talking about xmpp, smack 4.1, but I haven t configured it properly yet. I think I ll go for socket.